# target previous $this

Tags: jquery

How do I target $this (from 'each' context) from inside 'click' function. I want to remove awkward .parents().find() code.

```
$('.layout.responsive').each(function () {
    $('.area.optional', this).before('<a href="#" class="toggle_responsive" onClick="return false">Show details</p>').hide();
    $('.toggle_responsive', this).click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.layout.responsive').find('.area.optional').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is of course the same as everybody else's here, but I think using this syntax is much cleaner and will accomplish the same as the code you're using right now.

```
$('.layout.responsive').each(function () {
    var ar = $(this).find('.area.optional').hide(), 
        showDetail = $('<a />', {
        href: '#', 
        class: 'toggle_responsive', 
        text: 'Show details',
        click: function(){
            ar.toggle();
            return false;
        }}).insertBefore(ar);
});
```

Instead of inserting in a HTML string, we can use the new syntax introduced in jQuery 1.4 to do this much more cleanly, and without the messy inline event handler you're using right now.

Comment: appreciate suggestion. its less readable but probably better.

Comment: +1 I'd use this one. Better than creating an element, losing reference to it, then having to immediately find it again in the DOM to assign the click.

Answer (score 7):

Save it in a named (non-special) variable:

```
$('.layout.responsive').each(function () {
    var area = $('.area.optional', this).before('<a href="#" class="toggle_responsive" onClick="return false">Show details</p>').hide();
    $('.toggle_responsive', this).click(function () {
        $(area).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: So 'var area', not 'var $area'?

Comment: It makes no difference, but typically javascript variables don't begin with `$`. Note that jQuery does use the `$` sigil as a function name, but it doesn't prefix any other identifiers with `$`

Comment: awesome, works. thanks for sharing. will prefer this as later is also useful, but for other goals.

Comment: marked this as accepted since its my kind of level :), but be sure to check out other answers, so far Yi Jiang gave version with advanced syntax and ThiefMasters answer is usable if you need $this available for later call. Thanks again!

Comment: Since `area` is already an jQuery object, why are you calling `$` on it again inside the event handler? And why not move the `onClick="return false"` into the click handler instead of leaving it there?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply store it in a variable:

```
$('.layout.responsive').each(function () {
    var $elem = $('.area.optional', this).before('<a href="#" class="toggle_responsive">Show details</p>').hide();
    $('.toggle_responsive', this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $elem.toggle();
    });
});
```

Also note the `e.preventDefault();` call which does pretty much what your `onclick="return false;"` did but in a much cleaner way.

Comment: Yuck with the $dollar_named_variables.

Comment: Seems to be kind of common practise to use $that for jQuery objects.

Comment: Also, I think the OP wants the outer "this" available from the inner function, not in a later call

Comment: I like the dollar naming convention... lets you know when it refers to a jQuery object or a DOM element.

Comment: I expect every programmer to be able to adapt a solution to fit his needs. But reading the question again I think you are right.

Comment: jQuery only uses one dollar name, and that's `$` itself. No other jQuery method or variable starts with a `$`, only ones named by the programmer (and personally I don't agree that that's useful)